# partially trusted reading app.config on Windows 7 in network share

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, .net-3.5, network-share

I'm getting this error in Windows 7 64 bits:

An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for '': That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.

This happens when I try to read a config section, the section is mapped to a class that is in a DLL in the GAC, I'm using Visual Studio 2010 targeting the framework 3.5, I'm in a domain and the exe is running from a network share, the exe is signed.

This is failing only on Windows 7, an XP Machine can run the app just fine from the same network share, I'm using my domain account on both machines.

Does anyone know why this is failing on Windows 7?, thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Fixed using this command:
caspol -cg 1.2 FullTrust

The Intranet Zone had the LocalIntranet permissions set, (don't know why it was LocalIntranet, it should be FullTrust).

Thanks to dreynold.

Comment: Both you and dreynold are champs - %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CasPol.exe -cg 1.2 FullTrust did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Having bumped into similar trouble when our IT department did a stealth upgrade of users' machines to Windows 7, I suspect you may need to update the trust level with caspol.exe

For XP we would normally run:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CasPol.exe -q -m -ag 1.2 -url file:\\s:\* FullTrust
```

but now with Win7 it has changed to:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CasPol.exe -q -m -ag 1.2 -url file:\\s:\* FullTrust
```

Comment: still does not work, in a related question in 3.5 SP1 the intranet zone is full trust by default no?, at least that's what happens in XP.

Comment: That's not been my consistent experience, but then I'm not an expert on the nitty-gritty of the Windows security model.  I wonder why it's is giving you a 'partially trusted' message, rather than the usual 'untrusted' that I've been fighting.  Given that your executable (and associated DLLs, I presume) is signed, and the DLL is in the GAC, it still feels like domain resource trust issues are to blame here.